# IPv6: Destination unreachable: Address unreachable

Tags: routing, ipv6, gateway, gentoo, hetzner

My server can't ping/reach any other outside.

ping6 works for my local *fe80::468...* address as well as the *2a01:4f8...*, but **not** for *fe80::1*!

**Errors/Troubles/Issues:**

---

**ip neigh show**

```
fe80::1 dev eth0  FAILED
```

**ping6 2001:4860:4860:8888** (*Google*)

```
PING 2001:4860:4860:8888(2001:4860:4860:8888) 56 data bytes
From 2a01:4f8:202:43d5::2 icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
```

**ping6 -I eth0 fe80::1**

```
PING fe80::1(fe80::1) from fe80::468a:5bff:fe2c:3d6a eth0: 56 data bytes
From fe80::468a:5bff:fe2c:3d6a icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
```

**ping6 -I 2a01:4f8:202:43d5::2 fe80::1**

```
PING fe80::1(fe80::1) from 2a01:4f8:202:43d5::2 : 56 data bytes
From 2a01:4f8:202:43d5::2 icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
```

**Setup**

---

**ip -6 a**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 2a01:4f8:202:43d5::2/64 scope global
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::468a:5bff:fe2c:3d6a/64 scope link
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**ip -6 route**

```
2a01:4f8:202:43d5::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
default via fe80::1 dev eth0  metric 2  pref medium
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Why do you use fe80::1 as a gateway? That is probably wrong. Ping all routers and you should receive a response from the actual gateway address: `ping6 -c 1 -I eth0 ff02::2`

Comment: Because this gateway was the default at my controlpanel and rescue-system. `ping6 -c 1 -I eth0 ff02::2` results in 100% packet loss.

Comment: You should contact Hetzner. It looks like something is wrong with their stuff.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The dedicated servers I have at Hetzner use `fe80::1` as the default gateway. The vservers I have at Hetzner use a routable IPv6 address as the default gateway.

Comment: @ambiente1 Does it work if you use `2a01:4f8:202:43d5::1` as gateway?